# What is the best method to watch multiple folders for large amount of incoming files

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to watch 14 different folders (each in the same parent folder) for file download activities. Each of these folders will receive a 50k file 3-4 times a second.

I need to process these files and store them in a different location. My question is, what would be the most elegant way to keep a watch on the incomming files?

Should I use 14 `FileSystemWatcher` each one "watching" a folder and use the events fired from them to do my processing?

Or would a timer be more useful here? I could use one timer and then iterate through all 16 folders and their files.

Both methods feels bulky, is there another way I haven't thought of?

Any thoughts and ideas are much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Just realised I can instead of using sixteen `FileSystemWatcher` instances, I can just use one and set the `IncludeSubdirectories` property to TRUE.

Will this watcher be able to catch every incoming file though? There'll be about 3 x 14 = 42 incoming files a second.

Comment: I'd say "no" to "Should I use 16 `FileSystemWatcher`?", but then again, I'm wondering what problems you're encountering here; is `FileSystemWatcher` failing for you in some way? Is it apparent you need a more efficient, or lower level mechanism?

Comment: Can you watch a parent folder with FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm currently going the FileSystemWatcher route, just thought I'll ask the question before wasting my time with something if it isn't really viable. Sixteen different FileSystemWatchers just didn't feel "right" for me, but I'll continue this path and update here if I run into any problems.

Comment: @username Yes it's possible. You could set the `IncludeSubdirectories` property to true. But I doubt the performance will be good with so many files getting created.

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time, thanks for the replies, I was not aware that `FileSystemWatcher` had a `IncludeSubdirectories` property. Thanks @username for pointing out the obvious :)

Comment: @DanC225 At times, even _one_ `FileSystemWatcher` just isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, you can use `FileSystemWatcher` and similar solutions.

But, it seems like your problem is deeper than simply watching files. You should stop and ask yourself - is it even right approach to have 3-4 files created *every* second?

This problem just begs for employing some kind of database instead. Almost any database worth its salt will be able to handle this load without much effort. And, you would be able to use database triggers as your instant notification mechanism.

Comment: The files are downloaded via FTP and the server is receiving files from 14 different systems, I need to process these files as they are downloaded and move them to different locations

Comment: Just a note: is the files are flagged as temporary during creation then they aren't going to be written to disk and only reside in memory.

Comment: Do you need to save the files to disk? Is it possible to keep the files in memory instead?

Comment: the downloading is done via FileZilla, not via my software. Would it be easier to write my own FTP server app and then use that instead of waiting for filezilla to download it for me? Then I should be able to access each file as they get downloaded

Comment: @DanC225: how big downloaded files are? like average and maximum size

Comment: about 50k average, some can reach 100k though

Comment: Well, you can set it up as HTTP server and save files in database as BLOBs. If you can change client software, change it to use HTTP instead. If you cannot do that, use ProFTPd or vsftpd and hack it to save your files into database as BLOBs.